# Why doesn't c# allow multiple return values?

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering...Why doesn't C# allow multiple return values?

At the moment we express out intent to return multiple values via returning a class or using `out` - as shown below.

```
static void Check(MyTask task )
{
    if (GoodReasonsNotTo(task))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("There are good reasons not to do this.");
    }
}

public static int UglyDo( MyTask task, out string response )
{
    Check(task);
    //...
    response = "Done";
    return 7;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = new MyTask("Add multiple return values");

    string response;
    var err = UglyDo(task, out reponse));
}
```

The code above could be expressed differently:

```
static void Check(MyTask task )
{
    if (GoodReasonsNotTo(task))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("There are good reasons not to do this.");
    }
}

public static (int, string) PrettyDo(MyTask task)
{
    Check(task);
    //...
    return 7, "Done.";
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = new MyTask("Add multiple return values");

    var (err, response) = PrettyDo(task); 
}
```

Is there anything special about return values vs function parameters? The look the same, they do the same things. Why weren't they made equal?

Also, could it support it the future?

BTW. The StackOverflow's syntax highlighter deals with it nicely - this surely means it would be a good thing.

Comment: I guess the Go programming language actually has this.

Comment: Perhaps because there were other means to achieve the same, e.g. use a small class with 2 members or a Tuple<>. All this new stuff makes C# harder to read for people who e.g. have C++ background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny that you ask.  It was just announced that it [*will* be supported in C# 7.0 [MSDN]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

Comment: Awesome link, thank you. Allowing returning tuples isn't really the real deal though. The .Item1 bit is ugly.

Comment: @Tymski If you used C# 7 it was at best a preview.  Feel free to file a bug report or contribute to the discussion on github: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347.  Destructuring (so you don't need .Item1 etc) like in other languages is included.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it was "just" announced, it's been in the plans for C#7 for months.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. This is actually currently supported by some higher-level languages (like Go) as well as at least some assembly languages, such as MIPS, which [reserves several registers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253512(VS.80).aspx) for arguments as well as two for return values (but this is at least partially convention rather than some actual physical difference between the registers). In that more general sense, there isn't anything particularly "special" about return values.

In terms of why this isn't directly supported in C# yet, I'm speculating a little here but C#'s still heavily geared towards object-oriented development. Even features like anonymous functions are implemented "under the hood" in an object-oriented manner, so I suspect that if they do end up doing something like multiple return values in the future it'll also essentially be syntactic sugar for creating and returning an object. So, basically, you're explicitly returning an object now and maybe in the future it'll implicitly return one.

**Edit:** Right now the closest we get to multiple return values is probably Tuples, which unfortunately has very inconvenient syntax in C# right now (they're far more convenient to use in some other .NET languages, notably F#, which I'd really like to see gain more prominence, but that's just my opinion I guess). Apparently they're looking at improving that in future versions of C#, which could be as close as we're going to get for awhile (which I suppose would be in keeping with my suspicion that whatever they do in terms of multiple return values will just be syntactic sugar for an object).

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a novice in C#, but wouldn't a workaround like this help you?
Create a new class with the parameters desired and create a function returning that class.

```
public static testClass PrettyDo(MyTask task)
{
    Check(task);
    //...
    testClass answer = new testClass();

    answer.param1 = 7;
    answer.param2 = "Done.";

    return answer;
}

public class testClass
{
    public int param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because we do that all the time (return classes). No because in simple cases even a simple class is an overkill ( and also think value vs reference types and other little but important things).

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static Tuple<int, string> PrettyDo(MyTask task)
{
    Check(task);
    //...
    return Tuple.Create(7, "Done.");
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = new MyTask("Add multiple return values");

    var result = PrettyDo(task); 
    var err = result.Item1;
    var response = result.Item2;
}
```

It doesn't support unpacking like some higher level languages, but it's pretty close to what you're after.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, my question is more of design question rather than trying to find a way to achieve it. +1 Anyway :)